# Python function to map True, False, and None to symbols for display

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a use case in which I need to check whether a given value is explicitly `True` or `False`:

```
def stringify(value):
    """Returns the string representation of the value."""

    if value is None:
        return '-'

    if value is True:
        return '✓'

    if value is False:
        return '✗'

    return str(value)
```

I know, that in most cases, where you just need the *truthiness*, you'd just do `if value:`. But here this will not suffice, since I want zero `int`s and `float`s to be displayed in their decimal form as well as empty `list`s, `set`s `dict`s as such.
Is the above code acceptable or should I rather check using `isinstance(value, bool)` first and then do `if value:`?

What's the *least surprising* way to go?

**Usage Context**
The function is part of an API that converts database records to terminal output:
MariaDB → [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) → API → terminal

Example output:

```
$ termutil ls -T 1000
  ID  TID         CID  VID  OS                     IPv4 Address               Deployed  Testing  Tainted  Address                                           Annotation                      
 214    1        1000    -  HIDSL latest              XX.Y.Z.75                      -        ✓        ✗  Musterstraße 42, 123456 Irgendwo                      -                               
 215    2        1000    -  HIDSL latest              XX.Y.Z.76                      -        ✓        ✗  Musterstraße 42, 123456 Irgendwo                      -                               
 216    3        1000    -  HIDSL latest              XX.Y.Z.77                      -        ✓        ✗  Musterstraße 42, 123456 Irgendwo                      -                               
 217    4        1000    -  HIDSL latest              XX.Y.Z.78                      -        ✓        ✗  Musterstraße 42, 123456 Irgendwo                      -                               
 218    5        1000    -  HIDSL latest              XX.Y.Z.79                      -        ✓        ✗  Musterstraße 42, 123456 Irgendwo                      -                               
 219    6        1000    -  HIDSL latest              XX.Y.Z.80                      -        ✓        ✗  Musterstraße 42, 123456 Irgendwo                      -                               
 330    7        1000  399  HIDSL latest             XX.Y.Z.182                      -        ✗        ✗  Musterstraße 42, 123456 Irgendwo                      -                               
 508    8        1000    -  HIDSL latest             XX.Y.Z.189                      -        ✗        ✗  N/A                                                   -
```

Comment: Personally not fond of the end case here. What if I pass in '-', '✓', or '✗'? The returned value will be ambiguous. Or you could specify that you don't accept strings in your docstring or type contract.

Comment: @LukeSawczak You'll always have ambiguity when converting objects to strings if the object may be a string. Your example also applies to `[]`→`"[]"` and `"[]"`→`"[]"` etc.

Comment: -- Unless you catch that case and have defined behaviour for it :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak I don't mind *this* kind of ambiguity in my use case.

Comment: Fair enough, and it's not key to your question anyway. Just noting it :)

Comment: The best answer is in your question. I see no improvements below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because the code snippet is so small and missing any other context, it's hard to identify any problems in scaling / that may arise elsewhere in the code. Thus if you want a more tailored answer, you should add more code.

Yes, this is fine.

Regarding the `isinstance()` check, no. That only adds an extra level of indentation without justification.

Answer (score 20):

Personally I'd use a dictionary, as they're pretty much [the standard switch statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3103).
If you just use a normal dictionary with just `True` as the key, then it has the down side of returning `'✓'` for both `True` and `1`.
And so you can make a dictionary with the key being a tuple of the value and the type.

```
_stringify_values = {
    (type(None), None): '-',
    (bool, True): '✓',
    (bool, False): '✗'
}

def stringify(value):
    try:
        return _stringify_values[(type(value), value)]
    except (KeyError, TypeError):
        return str(value)
```

You can also simplify the input if you want to:

```
_stringify_values = {
    None: '-',
    True: '✓',
    False: '✗'
}
_stringify_values = {(type(k), k): v for k, v in _stringify_values.items()}
```

---

If you plan on using this a lot, you can also make a simple class to contain all the special logic too. By using [`collections.abc.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping):

```
import collections


class TypedMapping(collections.abc.Mapping):
    def __init__(self, values):
        self._dict = {
            (type(k), k): v
            for k, v in values
        }

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return self._dict[(type(key), key)]
        except TypeError as e:
            raise KeyError(str(e)) from e

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._dict)

    def __iter__(self):
        return (k for _, k in self._dict)

stringify = TypedMapping([
    (None, '-'),
    (True, '✓'),
    (False, '✗'),
    (1, 'one')
])

for i in (None, True, False, 1, 'True', {}, ()):
    print(stringify.get(i, str(i)))
```

Comment: This in over-engineered solution looking for a problem where none exist.

Comment: The general overengineering aside, why in the world would you catch a `KeyError` eather than using `return _stringify_values.get((type(value), value), str(value))`

Comment: @JohannesPille Because there is already the need to catch for `TypeError` when the key is unhashable; so no need to make the line less readable.

Comment: @Will I don't think using a dictionary and a `try` is over-engineered. The class is, which is why I prefaced it with "if you plan on using this a lot" .

Answer (score 14):

Even though `return` cuts the chain short if one matches, I would prefer to use an `elif` chain here, because it is more obvious, but YMMV (especially with automatic linters):

```
def stringify(value):
    """Returns the string representation of the value."""
    if value is None:
        return '-'
    elif value is True:
        return '✓'
    elif value is False:
        return '✗'
    return str(value)
```

Apart from that there is no real alternative, because all other approaches will fail on the difference between `0` and `False`, which you can only get with `is` or on unhashable types (like `list`).

The only other possibility I see is replacing the values for `True, False, None` after the conversion to `str`, unsing `str.translate`, but this would be unable to differentiate `None` and `"None"`.

Comment: I actually just got rid of the `elif`s because of the noise that `pylint` was making from it.

Comment: That's a case for telling the linter to be quiet, rather than modifying your code to placate it.

Comment: `pylint`'s default settings are terrible.

Comment: IMO using `elif` actually makes the code a little worse, because it implies a reachable `else` branch. Introducing tautologies like that doesn't clarify anything to me: each time I read code with a redundant statement like that I lose a *liiittle* bit of faith in whoever wrote that having a clear mental model of their own control flow. Code can be "too clever", but it can also sometimes be too ...dumb?

Comment: @Will As I said, YMMV. I generally agree with you, but here I like it because it is clear at a glance that the cases are mutually exclusive. Somehow that is less obvious for me with the original `if` chain.

Comment: If you're adding elifs here, then why not also add an else: before the final line?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: I was contemplating doing that, but felt that a final `return` was just as clear, and does not include the silliness of the rest of it.

Comment: I would change it either to what @RemcoGerlich said or to setting ``result=str(value)`` at the beginning, then having the ``if``/``elif`` setting ``result`` to special values and then returning ``result`` in the end.

Answer (score 9):

I might use nested conditional expressions, which can be formatted rather cleanly:

```
def stringify(value):
    return ('-' if value is None else
            '✓' if value is True else
            '✗' if value is False else
            str(value))
```

For a small set of hard-coded checks, the readability outweighs the linear search to find the matching case.

Comment: -1 for the inline conditionals, but +2 for "For a small set of hard-coded checks, the readability outweighs the linear search to find the matching case.". Could not agree more.

Answer (score 6):

A remark about the function name and the docstring:

```
def stringify(value):
   """Returns the string representation of the value."""
```

- `stringify`: May or may not be okay, possibly `to_string` would be nicer.
- `value`: What value? Does it have to be a numeric value? A value of any kind, but no object? The variable name does not make this fully clear

> Returns the string representation of the value.

This does not document what the function does, because after reading I do not know ...

- What values are allowed? Are there any restrictions?
- What defines a "string representation" of a value? for `float`s alone there are a lot of possible representations. Nested structures, objects and so on can have many possible representations as well, from `[object]` up to a full serialization.
- Why should I use this function instead of `str`/`unicode`? What is the difference?
- Is there any special handling for some data types? I do not know, that your representation of `True` will be an unicode character and not `"True"`, `"1"`, or `"true"` which would follow the principle of least surprise.

In addition it mixes a special handling for `bool` values with a default handling for everything else. Possibly it should be `bool_to_unicodesymbol` and raise a `ValueError` if the input is no boolean value.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the ambiguity resulting from inputs like `'-'` and `'[1, 2]'`, I suggest replacing your `str(value)` call with a `repr(value)` call.

If you wish to extend this to the point where a linear search might cause unnecessary delays, you will need to use the `id` of these singletons to avoid issues when stringifying unhashable types:

```
try:
    # Using the id() of singletons to support unhashable types
    return appropriately_named_lookup_table[id(value)]
except KeyError:
    return repr(value)
```

Make sure you document this if you end up doing it, and keep in mind that although it might seem like it works for integers `in range(-5, 256)` this is a CPython implementation detail only.

Comment: +1 for considering `repr` , but the code seems me more useful for "user" than "developer"

Comment: The OP said that ambiguity was unavoidable.

Comment: As I commented above, the ambiguity is not a problem at all. On the contrary, I don't want the `'` surriunding my strings.

Comment: You could use a defaultdict instead of catching exceptions.

Comment: @allo Really? I didn't know that supported passing an argument! But no, since it'd have to use a `ctypes` cast from the `id`, which just happens to be the address in CPython but isn't required to.